# Timestamp in file output

Tags: bash, file, raspberry-pi, timestamp, rtsp

I've got a script running, which should output a timestamp in the filename.
It works but it's keeping the same date and time.

What am I doing wrong?
The script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash FOR 192.168.2.20
    
cd Videos/VideoCaptures
counter=0
while :
do  
    echo "\nCount No = " $counter
    currentdate=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%Hhr-%Mmin-%Ssec"`
    sudo openRTSP -D 1 -c -B 10000000 -b 10000000 -4 -Q -F $currentdate -P 3600 -w 1920 -h 1080 -K -t -u admin 12345 rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.2.20:554/ch0_0.h264
    counter=$((counter+1))
done
exit
```

I'm getting this:

[File listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQDEv.png)

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! I edited your post to make it a bit shorter and easier to read. I can't spot the issue at first glance, could you add the output of the script when it is running? Maybe add another `echo $currentdate` to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks!

The output, are in the screenshot (The files)
How do you mean; "another echo $currentdate" ?
Where should i put this? Can you make an "how to"?

Answer (score 1):

Your line `echo "\nCount No = " $counter` should show you that the `openRTSP` never terminates. You probably have only one line `Count No = 0`.

Actually, this is the same `openRTSP` program that has created all those files, hour after hour (due to the `-P` option). The name of each file it created is prefixed by the `-F` option, which contains the date when your started `openRTSP`.

Comment: But is it possible to get an date+time in every file-output?
How should look this script then?

Comment: @Neao See `openRTSP`'s manual. If you want to use the prefix as a date and keep a loop like this, then one thing is certain: `openRTSP` must not run continuously.